# Can you create a graphical view of a database using SSDT?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

I have just started using SSDT. Is there any way I can get a graphical view of my database and  the relations between the tables?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there's any visualization tools in Visual Studio itself to draw a database diagram (would be nice, though!) - I guess you'll have to deploy to SQL Server and then use e.g. SQL Server Management Studio's `Database diagrams` feature to achieve this for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, no there isn't, nor is there any 3rd party plugin for it either (as far as I have been able to establish).

There was some talk a while ago about it possible coming, though no timescales were mentioned: 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ssdt/thread/853b8ec1-33a2-49c5-9ac2-b93d89e8b859/

Unfortunately, I understand that Gert is no longer working on SSDT, so it may no longer be in the pipeline

Answer (score 0):

There's no diagramming tool within SSDT. You'll have to resort to another tool I'm afraid however that tool will (naturally) require you to deploy your SSDT project first.

A diagramming tool that builds upon the in-memory model that SSDT builds under the covers would be great. Its not there today though.

JT